# Cannot create bibliography in TeXstudio

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

text\citet{Gettier2}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Gettier}

\end{document}
```

and the following reference file Gettier.bib saved in the same archive:

```
@Article{Gettier2,
    author = {Edmund Gettier},
    title = {Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?},
    journal = {Analysis},
    year = {1963},
    OPTkey = {key},
    volume = {23},
    number = {6},
    pages = {121-123},
    OPTmonth = {month},
    OPTnote = {note},
    OPTannote = {annote},
}
```

Unfortunately I only get a ? after text when compiling, and not the reference intended.

What is going wrong?

Comment: have you run bibtex to generate the references? you need to run latex then bibtex then latex again

Comment: I don't quite understand. I use Texstudio and press F5 (Build and view) and F6 (Compile) and then F5 again. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I do not lnow that editor, but those keys will be set to run some commands, if they are just running pdflatex then the bibliography wil not be generated. You need to run bibtex after running latex, then run latex again. There will be some key or menu option that runs bibtex.

Comment: I understand now, it is F8. Unfortunately it gave me an error:

"Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber "document"

INFO - This is Biber 2.5
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'document.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)"

Comment: well obviously it didn't run bibtex but biber. You will have to adjust this in the settings and change biber to bibtex.

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your query since the issue is related to TeXstudio, not `natbib`.